# Numbering the occurrences themseleves using sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk

How can I number the occurrences of the matched pattern using sed. For eg: I have a file with data in the format :

```
line1
line2
line3
********
line4
line5
********
line6
line7
line8
line9
*******
line10
```

And I need the output in the format below:

```
line1
line2
line3
1*******
line4
line5
2*******
line6
line7
line8
line9
3******
line10
```

So, the basic requirement is replacing the first occurrance of **/^\*/** with 1, second occurrance with 2, third with 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right tool for the right job. This is tailor made job for awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /\*\*\*\*/{print ++a $0; next} {print}' file
line1
line2
line3
1********
line4
line5
2********
line6
line7
line8
line9
3*******
line10
```

**Or else pure BASH solution:**

```
while read l; do
    [[ $l == *'****'* ]] && l=$((++x))"$l"
    echo "$l"
done < file
```

Comment: @fedorqui: Thanks so much, edited and provided BASH solution also.

Comment: @rsharma: Any specific reason of un-accepting it after more than 3 months?

Comment: @anubhava must be a mistake

Answer (score 2):

`sed` cannot do any arithmetics. Use a different tool, e.g. Perl:

```
perl -pe 'print ++$i if /^\*+$/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^\*/!b;x;:a;s/9(_*)$/_\1/;ta;s/^(_*)$/0\1/;s/$/:9876543210/;s/(.)(_*):.*(.)\1.*/\3\2/;s/_/0/g;x;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' file
```

As a solution it is little more than a joke, however `where there's a will there's a way`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner (awk):

```
 awk '/^[*]+$/{$0=++i$0}7' file
```

Comment: Vote for this, better one.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk instead:

```
 awk '{if ($0 ~ /[*]+/) printf "%d%s\n", ++a, substr($0, 2); else print $0;}' file
```